# Display json in a readable format in a new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to display json in a readable format, in a new window. I've got a button and when you click a new tab appears with the json inside. However, in the new window the json is still not formatted, it appears as a plain text. In the `console.log`, however, it is formatted properly. I don't understand why it's different.

```
$('.showRawJson').click(function () {
    $.getJSON('somelink', function (json) {
        var myjson = JSON.stringify(json, null, 2);
        // In the console the json is well formatted
        console.log(myjson);
        var x = window.open();
        x.document.open();
        // Here in the new tab the json is NOT formatted
        x.document.write(myjson);
        x.document.close();
    });
});
```

Comment: For starters you have a mismatched `"`, but I assume that's due to editing your code for the question.

Comment: @user3793865 can you show your json output

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put it into a `pre` tag, and it will keep the whitespace during display. Your code changed a bit:

```
    var myjson = JSON.stringify(json, null, 2);
    console.log(myjson);
    var x = window.open();
    x.document.open();
    x.document.write('<html><body><pre>' + myjson + '</pre></body></html>');
    x.document.close();
```

Comment: Thanks. The pre tag solved my problem. I totally forgot about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like `JSON.stringify` and `<pre>` tag.

To use this, you would need to turn your string into an object then back into a string:

Example :

http://jsfiddle.net/yEez8/

```
var jsonStr = $("pre").text();
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
var jsonPretty = JSON.stringify(jsonObj, null, '\t');

$("pre").text(jsonPretty);
```